# Advantage of using WebAPI in asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Advantage of using WebAPI as ProjectType over InterNet Application in asp.Net MVC?
Is any other use of WebAPI and why it's introduce in MVC4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To name a few :

- ASP.NET web api can be selfhosted outside IIS
- ASP.NET web api is not specifically geared towards browsers...
- ASP.NET Web api makes making a (level 2/3) RESTful webservice easier

Answer (score 1):

I think that the biggest advantage WebAPI has over other solutions is the built in support for different formats such as XML , JSON, and the relative ease when adding your custom formats. Another advantage worth mentioning is the ability to support extensive OData without coding as much (can be as simple as returning IQueryable), and the support of objects.

That said, WebAPI still have scores of issues that need to be resolved, I keep getting questions from developers that find WebAPI can't resolve their methods, parameters that always result with NULL etc... so I wouldn't swear by it yet, we are all hoping to see a better version sooner rather than later.